# How to fake a response using sc-server

Tags: response, sproutcore

I want to execute this code in development mode:

```
App.statecharts.someState = SC.State.design({
  enterState: function() {
   SC.Request
      .getUrl('/someUrl')
      .json()
      .header({ 'Accept': 'application/json' })
      .notify(this, 'checkIsAnswer')
      .send();
  },
  checkIsAnswer: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

To do so I need to fake the response from the server.
Eg. `http://localhost:4020/someUrl` schould be a static JSON

How to fake this response using `sc-server`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sc-server` has a proxy.

Try adding `proxy '/someUrl', :to => 'myinternalserver.com:9090'` to your Buildfile.

You can then make your hard coded fake JSON response accessible from `http://myinternalserver.com:9090/someUrl`.  Any web server will do.

Hope this helps.